# Is it possible for IIS to block request coming from specific server

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-8, event-viewer, iis-logs

I am hosting a ASP.NET WEB API application on IIS 8. In our setup we have two Webservers. The way setup is designed, all the request hits a primary server (call it Server A) and then it simply redirects every request to our server (call it Server B) which is actually hosting ASP.NET WEB API application. All this was working fine for an year but yesterday suddenly it seems Server B decided to block every incoming request from Server A. During this time, if we directly access Server B, it was still serving data.

I looked at the IIS logs for the web site and there is absolutely no logs about the duration at which IIS was not responding. Event logs are also empty.

I looked at the CPU and Memory utilization on Server B and it not high.

I will enable [failed request trace](https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) on IIS now. But I am hoping meanwhile I can find some answers to this issue.

Comment: do you see any traffic on server A? did you try to use fiddler?

Comment: @Yuri: Yes, all the traffic comes through server A. And I can confirm there was lot of traffic during that time. But I did not used fiddler.

Comment: So, the problem is between server A and B. Can you login directly to the server A and using browser place a call to web api on the server B? What is the result of this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to Server A. Its  a good point but did not tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Fiddler, from response you might have a good clue on what is going on

Comment: The issue is mysteriously resolved now without any trace or log so I cannot use fiddler now. This communication model was working for last 1 year and suddenly it stopped and started to work again. I have checked event logs and IIS logs on the server with no luck.